# Reading in CSV files smaller than 10K from S3 with Ruby 1.9.2 p290

Tags: ruby, csv, amazon-s3, paperclip

The following code snippet works fine for CSV file sizes larger than 10 K.

```
lines = CSV.read(open(resource.csv(:original)))
```

This is reading the the CSV file stored in Amazon S3 using Paperclip gem.

If the file size is smaller than 10 K however, I get the following error:

ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert StringIO into String):

I googled and found the following post:

http://adayinthepit.com/?p=269

So I tried to use the fastercsv gem, when I ran my program again, here is the error that I get:

ActionView::Template::Error (Please switch to Ruby 1.9's standard CSV library.  It's FasterCSV plus support for Ruby 1.9's m17n encoding engine.):

Looks like it is a Catch-22.  How can I process files smaller than 10 K in ruby 1.9.2 p290?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Bharat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `CSV.read` is being handed a StringIO when it wants a String. If so, then you should be able to stick a `read` call in and switch to `CSV.parse` to make everyone happy:

```
lines = CSV.parse(open(resource.csv(:original)).read)
```